# Rails nested routing match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, routes, controllers, nested-routes

I am new to rails and have a tricky routing question.  I have a resource with a nested collection that maps to the controller of the type for the nested collection.   However the name of the collection does not map to the controller which I want to route the request to.

Basically the User model has many followers and followings.  These 2 collections map to the Follow model which has a follows controller with standard crud methods.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers, class_name: Follow, foreign_key: :user_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followings, class_name: Follow, foreign_key: :follower_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

follow.rb:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :followers_count
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User', counter_cache: :followings_count

  attr_accessible :user, :user_id, :follower, :follower_id

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :follower_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :follower_id

end
```

follows_controller.rb:

```
def index
  respond_with @follows
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resources :followers, :controller => "follows"
    resources :following, :controller => "follows"
end
```

rake routes:

```
api_v1_user_followers GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/followers(.:format)              api/v1/follows#index
                                POST   /api/v1/users/:user_id/followers(.:format)              api/v1/follows#create
       new_api_v1_user_follower GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/followers/new(.:format)          api/v1/follows#new
      edit_api_v1_user_follower GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/followers/:id/edit(.:format)     api/v1/follows#edit
           api_v1_user_follower GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/followers/:id(.:format)          api/v1/follows#show
                                PUT    /api/v1/users/:user_id/followers/:id(.:format)          api/v1/follows#update
                                DELETE /api/v1/users/:user_id/followers/:id(.:format)          api/v1/follows#destroy
    api_v1_user_following_index GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/following(.:format)              api/v1/follows#index
                                POST   /api/v1/users/:user_id/following(.:format)              api/v1/follows#create
      new_api_v1_user_following GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/following/new(.:format)          api/v1/follows#new
     edit_api_v1_user_following GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/following/:id/edit(.:format)     api/v1/follows#edit
          api_v1_user_following GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/following/:id(.:format)          api/v1/follows#show
                                PUT    /api/v1/users/:user_id/following/:id(.:format)          api/v1/follows#update
                                DELETE /api/v1/users/:user_id/following/:id(.:format)          api/v1/follows#destroy
```

I tried adding the :controller => 'follows' and that does correctly map both nested collection routes to the follows_controller.   However I get this error:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/users/2/following?auth_token=qhcT6CSHi3S7KrEnJtq6" for 10.0.1.72 at 2013-04-22 09:52:43 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::FollowingController):
```

Any ideas on how to correctly solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the FollowsController located and within which module? The rake routes shows and is expecting the controller to be in app/controllers/api/v1/ wihtin Api::V1 module.

Comment: The routes are nested in the correct namespace.  sorry for not including that!

Comment: I ended up adding custom actions to the users controller.  Very simple although not quite as resourceful.